# How can I make entities locally revisioned in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-envers

I've audited my entities with the @Audited annotation of hibernate. It has a simple mechanism, It creates a REVINFO table and also _AUD for each entity by default and make a foreign key in each _AUD table with relation of REVINFO table. But I want to make revisioning to local. It means that I want to move revision to each _AUD table and removing REVINFO table.

According to [Hibernate envers page](http://docs.jboss.org/envers/docs/)

> "locally revisioned", that is revisions would be created for it
>   independently. This wouldn't enable correct versioning of relations,
>   but wouldn't also require the "REVINFO" table.

But I don't know how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's only a discussion on what might be considered as a feature to implement in the future. Currently not possible.